# PopUpWindow crashes in Android if setOnClickListeners for its buttons are added

Tags: android, popupwindow

Apparently, this is a different case from the other PopUpWindows crashes that I found in Internet, because I manage to open and show the PopUpWindow, but the problem arises when I add code for the buttons that the PopUpWindow contains. The code segment for the window is:

```
ImageButton speedImageButton;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LMMoviesMainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popvideocontrols, null); // popvideocontrols is a GridLayout
videocontrolsGloPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 800, 178, true);
videocontrolsGloPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
videocontrolsGloPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
videocontrolsGloPopupWindow.setFocusable(false);
videocontrolsGloPopupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 37);
speedImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.speedImageButton);
```

If I add a click listener for a button, it crashes, e.g.:

```
speedImageButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {}
   });
```

It has thrown me these two types of errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference**

**BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not valid
```

Any idea? What should I try or modify? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: There must be a line where the crash logs must be refering to. It will be helpful of you could point that line and add code relevant to that line.

Comment: Where is the call of `setOnSeekBarChangeListener(...)`? Plus initialization of the related `SeekBar` instance?

Comment: OK. The SeekBar was just another control view in the window. If I only add the listener for the button, it still crashes exactly at the onclick listener: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference**

Comment: The first argument in `showAtLocation()` should be a `View` in the `Activity`, not the `PopupWindow`'s layout. Also, if `speedImageButton` is in the `PopupWindow` layout, you need to call `findViewById()` on `layout`. Same for the `SeekBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Thanks to Mike M.: Your suggestion solved my problem.
All I had to do was:
instead of: speedImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.speedImageButton);

associate the inflated View of the popvideocontrols.xml:

speedImageButton = (ImageButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.speedImageButton);